# Assign to anonymous struct value in map

Tags: go

I am using go 1.3.

How can I access the fields of the anonymous struct ValueType of the map ?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Words map[string]struct{
    pos   int
    n     int
}

func main() {
    w := make(Words)
    w["abc"].pos = 5 // cannot assign

    fmt.Println(w)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a value (your struct) to your key:

```
type S struct {
    pos int
    n   int
}
type Words map[string]S

func main() {
    w := make(Words)
    s := S{pos: 1, n: 2}
    w["abc"] = s 
    fmt.Println(w)
}
```

See this <kbd>[play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/mYsLWh4Uxp)</kbd> example.

Output:

```
map[abc:{1 2}]
```

See more at "[Go maps in action](http://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action)".

Then you can retrieve your value and assign:

```
sbis := w["abc"]
sbis.pos = 11
fmt.Println(sbis)
```

Output:

```
{11 2}
```

---

[In his example](http://play.golang.org/p/3sKscCyG-l), [OneOfOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145587/oneofone) proposes a getter in order to assign pos quicker, but creating if needed the right value (that is an instance of the struct):

```
func (w Words) get(s string) (p *ps) {
    if p = w[s]; p == nil {
        p = &ps{}
        w[s] = p
    }
    return
}
```

That allows:

```
w := Words{}
w.get("abc").pos = 10
```

Comment: Damn it, you beat me to it, you win again @VonC, I SHALL TAKE MY REVENGE. Just to point one thing out, `w["abc"] = S{pos: 1, n: 2}` works fine without all the pointer mojo, or if using pointers, something like http://play.golang.org/p/3sKscCyG-l would be more fitting.

Comment: @OneOfOne I didn't see your example immediately: I have included it in the answer for more visibility, with proper attribution;

Comment: Everything I was looking for, and more :D

Answer (score 9):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Words map[string]struct {
    pos int
    n   int
}

func main() {
    w := make(Words)
    v := w["abc"]
    v.pos = 5
    v.n = 42
    w["abc"] = v
    fmt.Println(w)
}
```

Output:

```
map[abc:{5 42}]
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I think the first `w["abc"]` could really be anything (like `w[""]`), since we just want its type

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value for a key this way.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    w := make(map[string]struct {
        pos int
        n   int
    })
    w["abc"] = struct {
        pos int
        n   int
    }{
        pos: 5,
    }

    fmt.Println(w)
}
```

Reading the value for a key is easier.

```
fmt.Println(w["abc"].pos)
```