# Map lookup via anonymous struct key

Tags: go

I have the following `map` whose key type is an anonymous `struct`:

```
var data map[struct{ pID, bID int }]string
```

Question: **How  would I go about constructing a key to actually get/set a value in `data`**?

I've tried these, which all result in compiler errors:

```
data[{1,2}] = "ok"
data[{pID: 1, bID 2}] = "ok"
```

It seems I cannot form a compound literal without having the type name, but there is no type name.

---

This related question uses an anymous `struct` as the *value* of a `map`, but not the *key*:

- [Anonymous struct as value to a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002711/anonymous-struct-as-value-to-a-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create anonymous keys as well, something like this:

```
func main() {

    data := map[struct{ pID, bID int }]string{}

    key := struct{pID, bID int}{1, 2}
    data[key] = "abc"

    data[struct{pID, bID int}{3, 4}] = "cha cha cha"


    fmt.Printf("%+v\n\n", data)

    fmt.Printf("'%s' '%s'\n", data[key], data[struct{pID, bID int}{3, 4}])
}
```

Full file: https://play.golang.org/p/2q11qiwxuI

Comment: That's not particularly terse. I think I'll just use a normal named struct. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome, yes it looks kinda verbose, but well at least you can use keys in the way that you want to on initialization time: https://play.golang.org/p/5KxO_SBJ97